# Kubernetes Ingress Configuration. Influxdb webinterface only shows white screen

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, kubernetes-ingress, influxdb, k3s

I deployed an k3s ansible managed kubernetes cluster via https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s-ansible. Then I applied influxdb deployment, Service and Ingress (also persistent volume and persistent volume claim) to the cluster. I expect the existing traefik installation to do the rest.

But when I try to access it via the ingress defined adress it just shows a white screen (not even that the site is not avaiable). When I access the service or the pod via port forwarding or nodeport it work as expected.

Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: influxdb-deployment
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: influxdb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: influxdb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: influxdb
        image: influxdb:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8086
        volumeMounts:
        - name: influxdb-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/influxdb
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: influxdb-secrets
      volumes:
      - name: influxdb-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: influxdb-pvc
```

Service:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: influxdb-service
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    app: influxdb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8086
      targetPort: 8086
      nodePort: 30000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tig-ingress
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  rules:
  - host: test.example.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /influxdb
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: influxdb-service
            port:
              number: 8086
      - path: /grafana
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: grafana-service
            port:
              number: 3000
```

I was of course expecting to see the login page of the influxdb as it does when I access it via NodePort or PortForwarding.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the `rewrite-target` (just `/`). Maybe this link will help you (the explanation as it's different ingress provider): https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/